# Fragment разрушается при вызове активити

Tags: java, android-fragment

Понимаю что мой вопрос весьма абстрактен, но я лучше опишу словами чтобы было понятно что происходит.

Есть майн активити в нем есть фрагмент 
Во фрагменте есть переменная `ArrayList`
Она инициализируется в `OnCreate` фрагмента. 
В методе `onStart` фрагмента она инициализируется конкретным значением и через адаптер заполняется `ListView` фрагмента.

Также есть `SettingsActivivty` оно пустое в нем пока ничего не отображается.

Так вот проблема в том что при нажатии кнопки `Settings` в `MainActivity` происходит переход в `SettingsActivity`. И все бы ничего, но когда нажимаешь клавишу назад 
Мы возвращаемся в майн активити, и опять вызывается метод onCreate фрагмента. и переменная `ArrayList` опять обнуляется. А ожидалось что вызовется метод `onResume` фрагмента.

Но раз вызывается метод `onCreate` это означает что фрагмент был уничтожен. 
Но почему?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtPP8.jpg как мы видим на этом изображении если активити закрывает другое активити, то вызывается метод `onResume`, но не у меня.

Дайте пожалуйста совет что можно сделать, могу привести необходимые куски кода если потребуется просто я не знаю что нужно чтобы решить этот вопрос. 
Код основного Main активити
    package com.example.android.sunshine.app;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        if (savedInstanceState == null) { //Если первый запуск активити
            // Создать новый контейтер
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new ForecastFragment(), "TAG").commit();
        } else {
            // Или найти предыдуший созданный
            ForecastFragment fragment = (ForecastFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TAG");
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment, "TAG").commit();
        }

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);


        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent,1);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Код фрагмента

```
package com.example.android.sunshine.app;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {
    public ForecastFragment() {
    }


    //ListView listView_forecast;
    private ArrayList<weatherAndTime> blocks;
    private ListAdapter adapter; // Адаптер

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Add this line in order for this fragment to handle menu events.
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        //Инициализируем адаптер
         blocks = new ArrayList<>(); // Пустой блок .
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        adapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), blocks); // Запиливаем новый адаптер.
        //Вьюшка
        ListView listView_forecast = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast); // Находим View
        listView_forecast.setAdapter(adapter); // Присваиваем его лист вью!
        //Лисенер
        listView_forecast.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { // Цепляем листенер он клика че ему делать
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent showDetail = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class).
                        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, adapter.getItem(position).toString());
                startActivity(showDetail);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecast_fragment, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
            FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask();
            weatherTask.execute("Omsk,RU", "json", "metric", "7"); // Запрашиваем погоду в асинхронном потоке
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }

    // Strings в AsyncTask имеется ввиду тип параметров, понятно что это массив.
    private class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<weatherAndTime>> { // Put URL string, return list of objects
        private final String LOG_TAG = FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();


        @Override
        protected ArrayList<weatherAndTime> doInBackground(String[] url_params) {
            if (url_params == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Error:Параметры запроса погоды пусты", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return null; // Exit if params null
            }

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;  // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
            BufferedReader reader = null;  // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
            String JSON; // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.

            try {
                // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
                // Possible parameters are available at OWM's forecast API page, at
                // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast

                // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection with params received.
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new UrlBuilder(url_params[0],
                        url_params[1],
                        url_params[2],
                        Integer.parseInt(url_params[3])).getUrl().openConnection(); // Connect from builded url

                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Read the input stream into a String
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();  // Был StringBuffer
                // Nothing to do.
                if (inputStream == null) return null;
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                    // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                    // buffer for debugging.
                    line += "\n";
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Бля джайсон чет не пришел ХЗ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return null; // Правоцирует IO EXCEPTION
                }
                JSON = buffer.toString();  // Получили JSON обьект парсим его

                JsonParser parser = new JsonParser(JSON); // Засовываем обьект в конструктор, там он сам разберется
                return parser.getResult(); // Возвращаем результат парсенья

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
                // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
                // to parse it.
                return null;
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }


        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<weatherAndTime> result) {
            if (result != null) { //Почему тут анчекед ассигмент и как с этим бороться
                blocks.clear(); //Очищает блокс
                blocks.addAll(result); //Обновляет blocks
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Код DetailActivity

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2014 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.example.android.sunshine.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DetailActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     /*   setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new DetailFragment())
            .commit();
        }
*/

    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.detail, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
   /* public static class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

        public DetailFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);

            TextView DetailView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.detailText);
            Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
            if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT))
                DetailView.setText(intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT));


            return rootView;
        }
    }*/
}
```

Код SettingsActivity

```
package com.example.android.sunshine.app;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.ListPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.KeyEvent;

/**
 * A {@link PreferenceActivity} that presents a set of application settings.
 * <p>
 * See <a href="http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/settings.html">
 * Android Design: Settings</a> for design guidelines and the <a
 * href="http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html">Settings
 * API Guide</a> for more information on developing a Settings UI.
 */
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity
        implements Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Add 'general' preferences, defined in the XML file
        // TODO: Add preferences from XML

        // For all preferences, attach an OnPreferenceChangeListener so the UI summary can be
        // updated when the preference changes.
        // TODO: Add preferences
    }

    /**
     * Attaches a listener so the summary is always updated with the preference value.
     * Also fires the listener once, to initialize the summary (so it shows up before the value
     * is changed.)
     */
    private void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
        // Set the listener to watch for value changes.
        preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);

        // Trigger the listener immediately with the preference's
        // current value.
        onPreferenceChange(preference,
                PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                        .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
        String stringValue = value.toString();

        if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
            // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
            // the preference's 'entries' list (since they have separate labels/values).
            ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
            int prefIndex = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);
            if (prefIndex >= 0) {
                preference.setSummary(listPreference.getEntries()[prefIndex]);
            }
        } else {
            // For other preferences, set the summary to the value's simple string representation.
            preference.setSummary(stringValue);
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Закоменнтированные куски кода в Detail Activity можно раскоменнтировать, это не важно все равно не работает.

Comment: Покажи каким образом ты подпихиваешь фрагмент для отображения в активити

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new ForecastFragment())
                .commit();

    }

Comment: по сути я создаю фрагмент в активити, в onCreate() активити, но для меня было большим рахочарованием ухнать что и активити тоже разрушается при переходе в соседнее активити, таким образом savedInstantState опять равна null, если бы я мог ее созранить фрагмент возможно не содавался бы заново но его все равно нужно было бы как то вызвать.

Comment: к сожелению я так и не смог понять в чем проблема, на другом смартфоне (возможно с большей памятью, активити не разрушается).
а вооббще как гарантировать чтобы активити не разрушалось ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Каждый раз, вызывая `new ForecastFragment()`, ты создаешь новый экземпляр фрагмента, который внутри себя и дергает onCreate. Поэтому советую в метод `add`в качестве третьего параметра добавлять тэг фрагмента, а перед повторным коммитом проверять, нет ли уже в `SupportFragmentManager` такого фрагмента (это делается методом `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);`), и если есть, заменять его вместо `new ForecastFragment()`

Хороший пример по теме расписан [тут](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/fragment-replace.php)

**Обновление**

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new ForecastFragment(), "TAG").commit();
} else {
    ForecastFragment fragment = (ForecastFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TAG");
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragment, "TAG").commit();
}
```

Comment: а можно примерный рабочий кусок кода, я с фрагметами на вы.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added.

Comment: при возврате из любого другого активити, в майн активити.

Comment: последняя строчка в вашем коде вызывает ошибку...

Comment: Сделайте так - если по тэгу менеджер смог найти фрагмент то тебя есть несколько вариантов: 1) вместо add вызывать replace, то есть заменить предыдущий фрагмент на тот же. 2 ) не вызывать метод add совсем, тогда отобразится тот же фрагмент что уже хранится в менеджере

Comment: Зависит от того какого поведения вы добиваетесь - переписывание данных в списке, или оставлять в том виде который был до этого.

Comment: к сожелению ничего не вышло. потому что при выходе из активити Datail Activivty сразу вызывается метод onCreate фрагмента, минуя OnCreate MainActivity. 

В случае же с SettingsActivity  при возврате в Main Activity переменная SavedInstance равна нулл, и условие в onCreate заново создает фрагмент.

Comment: с какой радости вызывается метод onCreate фрагмента, минуя onCreate MainActivity мне даже думать страшно.

Comment: Покажите код активити и фрагмента полностью

Comment: Вопрос обновлен, код выложен.